# Not possible to show my stages even being a simple empty pipeline

Tags: node.js, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, config, stage

Im trying to show the pipeline, but Jenkins didnt show anything.. i'm getting crazy how simple is the script and why not.

Anyone can give me a hand?

```
def call(body) {
def config = [:]
body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
body.delegate = config
body()

def util = new myscript (this,config);  


pipeline {
properties([[$class: .........]])

    node('slave-mine'){
                                
            stage('Preparing env') {
                env();
            }
            
            stage('Checkout') {
                checkout();
            }
}
}
```

Comment: Solved!
Just add in Jenkinsfile the input values like:

script_name{

blah = blabh1

}